# Reset (empty) knockout.js select list depending on selection in other select list

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have two select lists, one select list is populated by the selection of the other select list. I have subscribed to the value of the first select box to update the second list every time the value changes. What I am failing to discover is how to reset the second list if a user were to select the default "select ..." option in the first list.

To be clear, the process works, except when a user selects the default options. The Second list keeps the previous selection at that point.

Here's my code (this is an MVC 4 application).

ViewModel:

```
var DashboardReportViewModel = function (config, originalData) {
    var self = this;

    self.breweryCode = ko.observable();
    self.lineCode = ko.observable();
    self.GetBreweries = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.GetLines = ko.observableArray([]);

    var loadBreweries = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: config.GetBreweries,
            type: "GET",
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('loadBreweries error');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                self.GetBreweries(data);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    };

    var loadLines = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: config.GetLines,
            data: { breweryCode: self.breweryCode() },
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('loadLines error');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                self.GetLines(data);
            }
        });
    }

    loadBreweries();
    self.breweryCode.subscribe(function () {
        if (self.breweryCode() != undefined) {
            loadLines();
        }
    });
};
```

View:

```
<select class="ui-select" id="BrewerySelect" name="BrewerySelect" data-bind="options: GetBreweries,
                                                                                             optionsText: 'Text',
                                                                                             optionsValue: 'Value',
                                                                                             value: breweryCode,
                                                                                             optionsCaption: 'Select a Brewery'"></select>

<select class="ui-select" id="LineSelect" name="LineSelect" data-bind="options: GetLines,
                                                                                             optionsText: 'Text',
                                                                                             optionsValue: 'Value',
                                                                                             value: lineCode,
                                                                                             optionsCaption: 'Select a Line'"></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go this way:

```
self.breweryCode.subscribe(function () {
    if (!!self.breweryCode()) {
        loadLines();
    } else {
        self.GetLines([]);
    }
});
```

If `self.breweryCode()` is truthy an Ajax call will be placed to load the lines, otherwise that list is just emptied completely.

PS. If you like you could also use [`observableArray` utility methods](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#remove-and-removeall) to do `self.GetLines.removeAll()`.

Comment: This did the trick. @Vlad's was close, but the [] are required.

Answer (score 1):

You missing else case here:

```
 self.breweryCode.subscribe(function () {
    if (self.breweryCode() != undefined) {
        loadLines();
    }
    else {
        self.GetLines([]);
    }
});
```